# Why isn't SpringUtilities part of the core Java library?

Tags: java, swing, springlayout

I know `SpringLayout` is intended to be used by GUI builders, but this layout is useful when a developer wants to create a form-like layout. And the [`SpringUtilities`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringGridProject/src/layout/SpringUtilities.java) utility class makes manual coding with the layout manager *much* easier.

So, why isn't this part of the core Java library yet? Just curious...

Comment: +1 I agree with the poster.  I'm tired of finding some version of SpringUtilities online and copying the source into my project.  Maybe SpringUtilities needs some updating, but IMO it should be part of the core library.

Comment: there are lots of grest ideas (by former owner Sun) implements starts with A and ends with Z, e.g. JRS296 (Destop Aplication)....... Substance, SwingX, new owner new ...

Comment: It's a good tutorial example, but a very general API; they had to draw the line somewhere. Coincidentally, it's not featured in the NetBeans GUI designer.